# How to display instrument name always unshortened in MuseScore?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, software, musescore

MuseScore (2.0.3) displays the full instrument names only on the first line, on the other lines it is displayed shortened, like this:

[image]

1. How to force the application to show the instrument names always full?
2. Bonus question: How to influence the way of shortening the names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on the instrument name and click `Staff Properties`.

[image: MuseScore Staff Properties]

Type whatever you want under `Long Instrument Name` and `Short Instrument Name` to change what is displayed in each context.

More information is available on the MuseScore documentation [Staff Properties](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/staff-properties) page.